# Will global vars always be created before calling javascript functions?

Tags: javascript

Say I have the following:

```
<script>

var foo = {myFunc:function(){..some func}};

window.addEventListener('load',foo.myFunc(),false);

var bar = 'some var';

</script>
```

Will `window.addEventListener` always be able to set `foo.myFunc()` as a function to call on the load event? Is there any possibility that foo will be `undefined` when setting the event listener? When are `foo` and `bar` created, and when are they useable?

I am targeting only Safari 5.0+

Comment: You should probably be using `foo.myFunc`, not `foo.myFunc()`. The latter calls the function at the time you're binding, instead of making the function be the event handler. So unless `foo.myFunc()` returns a function, you don't want to call it immediately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variable definitions are "hoisted" to the top of a given scope so no matter where a variable is declared, it will exist before any code runs in that particular scope.

Variable assignments are executed sequentially as they are encountered in the javascript file.

So, `foo` will exist, but won't have its value until the assignment statement runs.

---

Also, your code should be this (remove the parens after myFunc):

```
window.addEventListener('load', foo.myFunc, false);
```

When you include the parens, the function is called immediately and its return value is passed.  If you want to just pass a reference to the function so `addEventListener()` can call it later, then you need to not include the parens.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, both `foo` and `bar` will be defined when your event handler executes.

Generally JavaScript executes synchronously, line by line. It starts at the top, and works downwards. However, this is a special case, as you're talking about variable declaration. In the case of variable and function declaration, ["hoisting"](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting.html) occurs. Functionally what's happening is you're written this:

```
var foo, bar;

foo = ...;

window.addEventListener(...);

var bar = ...;
```

So, while `foo` is obviously guaranteed to be defined, so is `bar`. Both variables will be closed over by the function, and available when it executes.

Comment: @cookiemonster Yes, very true.